# Web animations API callback function

Tags: javascript, animation, web-animations

I've just discovered the [Web Animations API](http://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations/), and I'm trying to figure out how to introduce a callback function for these animations..I've tried using the following

```
$('.box_wrapper')[0].animate([
    { right: '-100%' },
    { right: 0 }
], {
    fill: 'forwards',
    duration: 1000,
    onfinish: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Looking at the w3c spec on [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations/#the-animationplayer-interface) I thought that the `onfinish` property is what I'd need to use, but nothing happens.

I've also tried using the jQuery callback syntax;

```
$('.box_wrapper')[0].animate([
    { right: '-100%' },
    { right: 0 },
], {
    fill: 'forwards',
    duration: 1000
}, function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

But of course this doesn't work either. Any Ideas, I'm sure it's something simple, I've just not been able to find the info yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I nearly had it right, with a small tweak like so, the callback works;

```
$('.box_wrapper')[0].animate([
    { right: '-100%' },
    { right: 0 }
], {
    fill: 'forwards',
    duration: 1000
}).onfinish = function() {
    // do stuff
};
```

Comment: Just for future information, the W3C has removed the 'onfinish' attribute and replaced it with a 'finished' attribute which is a Promise. Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-web-animations-1-20150707/#dom-animation-finished

Comment: So what does that look like in the new syntax?

Comment: @CrowChick I believe you just replace `onfinish` with `finish`

Comment: Also, a heads up, `onfinish` was not replaces with `finish`: you can use either, for callback or promise syntax respectively :)